# what limitations wifi packet capturing imposes?

Tags: linux, networking, libpcap

What are the limitations of capturing wifi traffic using libpcap?

In terms of packet size, speed, packet loss, impact on the network, etc...

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score -1):

If you are just sniffing the airwaves to capture traffic, that is passive, and it causes the network no problems.

The limitations will be on the host you are using. A network card in promiscuous mode will not be able to be used for regular network connections while it is capturing traffic. You will also be capturing encrypted frames. Depending on the encryption method, you may not be able to see the actual frame payload.